# Sites to do free online jpa tests

Tags: java, jpa

Anybody know a good sites to do free jpa test online. specially multiple choice, these type of sites will help so much in training and understanding jpa(do not know if this is enough to allow me to ask this question here).

Comment: Not sure what you want. Something like http://www.codecademy.com/ for Java/JSP?